# How to take the result of sapply in data.table way R?

Tags: r, data.table, apply

**Goal** : Find the column index of first appearance in a file
* like excel Ctrl + F

```
# EXPECTED RESULT -- INDEX
[1] 2

# SAMPLE DT
DT <- data.table(A = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                 B = c(NA,"APPLE",NA,NA,NA),
                 C = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                 D = c(NA,NA,NA,"APPLE",NA))

lx <- grep("^APPLE$", sapply(colnames(DT), function(x) grep("^APPLE$",DT[,x],value = TRUE)))[1]

CURRENT METHOD
lx <- grep("^APPLE$", sapply(colnames(DT), function(x) grep("^APPLE",setDF(DT)[,x],value = TRUE)))[1]
```

**Problem**
it doesn't work if doesn't set setDF()

```
Error in `[.data.table`(DT, , x) : 
  j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'x' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..x]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.
```

**How to get the expected result without switching to data.frame (no `setDF()`) ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We loop through the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`), check if there is `any` TRUE values from the `grepl` output in each column, `unlist` and wrap with `which`

```
DT[, which(unlist(lapply(.SD, function(x) any(grepl( "^APPLE", x)))))[[1]]]
#[1] 2
```

---

A `base R` option with full string match would be `colSums` on logical matrix

```
which.max(unname(colSums(DT == "APPLE", na.rm = TRUE)))
#[1] 2
```

Comment: Its exactly what i need but not in document , awesome